# handling `onKeyUp` for a div

Tags: reactjs, events, keyboard, key, create-react-app

I want to handle a key clicked on the keyboard to run a function, I'm trying to do:

```js
<div className="playerContainer" onKeyUp={gameState.toggleCP}></div>
```

but there is no benefit (the div is scaled on the whole page), also I tried to add the handler to the default `App` class component, what to do?

Comment: If I can't do that, can I handle the event on the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as i understand, the problem is that `gameState.toggleCP` is not being called on `keyup` event.
`keyup` in order for event handler will be called on an element — element must be in focus.

#### TL:DR; add `keyup` listener onto the `document`

if you want to handle `keyup` event no matter which element is in focus — within React app component do the following:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

const gameState = {
  toggleCP: () => {
    // your function instructions
  },
};

export function MyComponent() {
  const handleKeyUp = useCallback(
    (event) => {
      gameState.toggleCP();
    },
    [gameState.toggleCP]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("keyup", handleKeyUp);
    };
  }, [handleKeyUp]);

  return <div className="playerContainer"></div>;
}
```

good luck fren!

Comment: where should I do the handler if I use class components

Comment: don't use class components, use functional components. but if you don't have a choice, do it in `componentDidMount` lifecycle method